# Migration - Create table from models to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In my Django project, I have four applications. I created a folder named **databasemodels**. In this folder I created a file: models.py; in which I implemented all the classes. And after, in the settings.py of the project, I put the name of the folder "**databasemodels**" in the INSTALL_APP, to facilitate the migrations.

Is it a good idea to work like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but I would highly recommend starting with the Django tutorial to fully understand the ins and outs of how Django models work:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

It will walk you through creating your first project, apps, models, views, and templates. Understanding how they all work together is very important for long term maintainability, and the introductory tutorial is fairly straightforward and shouldn't take too long to go through. Good luck!